# Does Hive custom script allows 2 or more reducers?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I was trying to use Hive custom script to perform my mapreduce work. I have the following code:

```
 ADD FILE reducer1.py;
    ADD FILE reducer2.py;

    FROM (
        FROM
         (
            SELECT i.time, i.id, i.response
            FROM table_1 i
            WHERE (i.id == 12345)
            CLUSTER BY time
          ) A
          REDUCE A.* USING 'reducer1.py'
          AS (x,y,z)
          CLUSTER BY x,y
    ) B
    REDUCE B.* USING 'reducer2.py'
```

However, this hive job was failed. When I looked at the log, the error is:

> "Cannot run program
>   "/mapred/d02/local/taskTracker/usr/jobcache/job_201311040808_1131/attempt_201311040808_1131_r_000000_0/work/./rtbmapper_auctionsimulator_reducer2.py":
>   java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)

I've added above two py files at the first beginning. Also when I run the reducer1 only, it went through without any problem. I used the following code:

```
ADD FILE reducer1.py;
FROM
     (
        SELECT i.time, i.id, i.response
        FROM table_1 i
        WHERE (i.id == 12345)
        CLUSTER BY time
      ) A
      REDUCE A.* USING 'reducer1.py'
```

So my question is: Does Hive custom script only allow one reducer? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you yes, Hive definitely can have more than one MapReduce job per query, and thus more than one Reducer. In theory, there's nothing wrong with that.

Unfortunately, I can't tell you what is failing here. From the error message, for some reason Hive is unable to find your reducer script... double-check it is where you think it is. Try executing each command 1 by 1 (add file..., add file..., select) and make sure none of them are failing or producing weird output. Finally, you could try this with an intermediate table. First query uses the first reduce script, and outputs to a temporary table. Second query runs the second reduce script on that temporary table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Joe. I did try your method in a step-by-step diagnosis. It turns out that the reason that Hive can not found the reducer2.py is because Hive fails to transfer output of reducer1 to reducer2. Therefore I got the following error message: "Hive Runtime Error while processing row". It seems that reducer2 can not take it as the input. However, I tried to output reducer1 as a txt file and it looks good. I used this txt file to feed reducer2 and there is no problem at all. Then I confused.